# 301 when www. infront of subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Could anyone please explain the redirect conditions and rule to achieve this:

1. User visits www.example.domain.com
2. 301 to example.domain.com

(Basically removing the www. from the URL, but ONLY when they access a subdomain.

It must allow access at www.domain.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

will redirect `www.example.domain.com` to `http://example.domain.com` it will even redirect `www.other.domain.com` to `http://oter.domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```